# Does restricting background data for an app turn off notifications too?

Tags: notifications, background-data

Does restricting background data also stop my phone from receiving notifications from restricted apps?

For example: I go to Settings > Data usage > Cellular data usage > Facebook, then I turn off 'Background data'.

Will I still receive notifications from Facebook?

Note* I am on Android: 7.1.2 and Device: Pixel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the app - the messaging service used.

For Facebook, yes, you will recieve notifications since it uses GCM (Google Cloud Messaging). So will other apps using GCM. GCM is a part of Google Play Services, which is not affected by restricting data

Other apps which don't use GCM will not show notifications. [Here's a list of apps](https://www.jucktion.com/tech/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-enabled-apps-list/) using GCM

Comment: Thanks!  I noticed you can turn off background data with Google Play Services.  It lists other apps included in usage as: Google Backup Transport, Google Account Manager and Google Services Framework.  Since it does not say Google Cloud Messaging does that mean Google Cloud Messaging will not have Background data turned off? 

I just want to make sure i'm not turning off that service by turning off Google Play Services background data.

Comment: Yes. You are right. GCM is not affected by restricting data

Answer (score 2):

If you're still connected to WIFI you should still receive those notifications. It sounds like you're just turning off the mobile data(as stated on my Galaxy S5), but not the WIFI data.

If you're not connected to WIFI you shouldn't receive notifications because it takes data to check for updates with the Facebook app.